# How to import all subclasses of a class at one time, in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cannot find interface declaration for ‘AbstractPickerView’,superclass of ‘AttackLayer’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269246/cannot-find-interface-declaration-for-abstractpickerview-superclass-of-attack)

There are 3 header files (a superclass and 2 subclasses):

```
//  A.h
@interface A : NSObject
@end

//  A1.h
#import "A.h"
@interface A1 : A
@end

//  A2.h
#import "A.h"
@interface A2 : A
@end
```

I want to import all subclasses of class `A`.
So I added 2 `#import` in A.h like this:

```
//  A.h
#import "A1.h" // added
#import "A2.h" // added

@interface A : NSObject
@end
```

But after adding them, the following compile errors occurred.

```
Cannot find interface declaration for 'A', superclas of 'A1'
Cannot find interface declaration for 'A', superclas of 'A2'
```

I know that this error can be solved by createing and importing the following file.

```
// ASubclasses.h
#import "A1.h"
#import "A2.h"
```

But I think `#import A.h` is more simple than `#import ASubclasses.h` to import subclasses.
And if I can use `#import A.h` to import subclasses, I don't need to create another file(ASubclasses.h).

Is there a way to use `#import A.h` to import all subclasses of A?
Or in general, how do you import all subclasses of a class?

Comment: @ParagBafna thanks for comment. but i want to know a good way or best practice to import all subclasses of a class with one #import. do you know it?

Comment: why are you importing in sub class in  a.h(superclass)?

Comment: @ParagBafna because if I import a1.h and a2.h in a.h, i can import all subclasses with `#import a.h` in other files which need to use a1 and a2.

Comment: create Common.h and import a1 and a2. now use Common.h in other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is because of an #import cycle . This happens when two header files import each other . You can just declare the class using @class and then import the headerfile in the implementation file.

Comment: thank you! I know #import cycle. How to import all subclasses in implementation file with one line code?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I dont think there is such a feature . If you import the subclass the super class also gets imported (as it will be imported by the subclass.).